# Strange JavaScript behavior in Android native browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webkit

Hi i want a simple onclick event where one image hides and the other one shows up.
Here is a Sample:
http://jsbin.com/abezob/1

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #ccc;">
<div id="reload" style="display: block">
<img width="24" height="24" src="http://info.kicktipp.de/img/mobil/reload.png" alt="reload" />
</div>

<div id="loading" style="display: none">
<img width="24" height="24" src="http://info.kicktipp.de/img/mobil/loading.gif" alt="loading" />
</div>
<p>
<a href="http://www.google.de/">Link to Google</a>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a").click(function() {
$("#reload").hide();
$("#loading").show();
});
</script>

</body></html>
```

I can't see the spinner on my device and I want to see it while the page is loading of course. The Sample works fine with Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but not with the native Android 4.1.2 Browser. Here is my UserAgent:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; de-de; GT-I9100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

Any suggestions appreciated.

UPDATE: Setting a timeout like shown below will make the spinner appear. However the spinner is animating only for the set timeout. So if the connection is bad and the loading will take some amount of time, the app looks non responsive. SAMPLE: http://jsbin.com/uxopuy/1 with 3 sec timeout

Comment: That page works fine on my Android phone from Chrome.

Comment: so you can see the spinning wheel, when you click on the link right?

Comment: Yes, it works on my phone just like on Chrome on the desktop. Now perhaps it works differently with the native Android browser; I'll try that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it would change anything, but you could try using something like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#reload").hide();
    $("#loading").show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = $this.attr("href");
    }, 500);
});
```

All this does is add a half second delay before actually navigating away. To me, that *might* help show the spinner when leaving the page.

I don't know why it's not "showing" the spinner on your phone, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's because the browser is leaving the page so quickly and you're not given much time to see the spinner.

Comment: It doesn't even need a half-second; even a very brief delay seems to "trick" the native Android browser into showing (not very well) the animated gif.  Chrome doesn't seem to have any problem with the original on my phone anyway.

Comment: if i put an alert after the changes, the spinner isn't showing too. so don't think the fast reload is my problem. the view just isn't updating.

Comment: I just tested this on my android (stock) browser and it works whereas the original code didn't.

Comment: the spinner is just animating for the set timeout. that's not what i'm looking for.